# Удаление всех свойств картинки

Tags: php, изображения

Доброго всем дня.
Ищу решение по уникализации картинок из PHP. Сделел переименование, уменьшение размера, наклон, обрезку, поворот и обнаружил свойства изображений, к которым не могу достучаться.

Эти свойства видно из под винды:
[image: img]

Как удалить все эти атрибуты из PHP? Гугл не помогает... возможно не правильно у него спрашиваю. Если не затруднит дайте наводку куда думать.

Comment: Может, эта библиотека поможет: http://ozhiker.com/electronics/pjmt/ ?

Comment: спасибо, посмотрю.